# Evaluating a KnockoutJS observable array in params passes a computed array

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a counter-intuitive thing happening with a component's `params` parameter, whereby an `observableArray` of objects is being passed through as a `computedObservable` when evaluated in the HTML.

```
<my-component params="myParameter: someObject.myObservableArray()"></my-component>
```

`someObject` is defined by an interface:

```
interface MyObjectType {
    myObservableArray: KnockoutObservableArray<MyDto>;
}
```

The parameters for `my-component` are then specified by another interface:

```
interface MyComponentParams {
    myParameter: Array<MyDto>;
}
```

Nothing particularly exciting happening here, but passing the observable array through and evaluating it in the constructor works fine. It seems to just be the evaluation within the `params` that is the issue.

Edit: Performing a `ko.unwrap()` on the `computedObservable` also results in the desired array. That's all well and good, but I'd like to understand why the evaluation results in a computed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-observable-expressions):

> To ensure that the child component can react to changes in the
>   expression value, **Knockout automatically upgrades this parameter to a
>   computed property**. So, the child component will be able to read
>   params.observableExpression() to get the current value, or use
>   params.observableExpression.subscribe(...), etc.
>
> In general, with custom elements, if a parameter’s evaluation involves
>   evaluating an observable, then **Knockout automatically constructs a
>   ko.computed value** to give the expression’s result, and supplies that
>   to the component.

(last emhpasis mine)

Comment: Ah, totally missed that from the docs. The latter part makes sense, especially when written as directly below that paragraph: _"If a parameter’s evaluation does involve evaluating one or more observables/computeds, it is passed as a computed property so that you can react to changes in the parameter value."_